# dotnet publish compiles Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch.dll with wrong version

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0, dotnet-publish

I have an interesting problem. When I use *dotnet publis* on my desktop PC it compile my project without errors on Linux run. When I compile the same project on my laptop there are one error on the Linux run, that complaining on **Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch**. As I tried to figure out what is wrong, I found out that *dotnet publis* on my laptop uses v2.2, if I build my solution from VS2019 it uses the correct version of 3.0 (my project is .net core 3).

interesting is that on my laptop i got generated *web.config* file with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath=".\portalnekretnine.com" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: F1180308-B6BA-4CCE-A131-F48B9B2DFD5E-->
```

any ideas?

here is how am I building from command line

```
dotnet publish D:\Projects\PortalNekretnine\Backend\PortalNekretnine.sln --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp3.0 --output .\build\ --self-contained false --runtime linux-x64 --verbosity quiet
```

My API's csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>portalnekretnine.com</AssemblyName>
    <RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>false</RunAnalyzersDuringBuild>
    <RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>false</RunAnalyzersDuringLiveAnalysis>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="4.9.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityModel" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Analyzers" Version="3.0.0-preview3-19153-02" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.OpenApi" Version="1.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="NSwag.Core" Version="13.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.9.0-dev-01133" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Exceptions" Version="5.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.AppSettings" Version="2.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="4.1.0-dev-00850" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters" Version="5.0.0-rc8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.6.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\portalnekretnine.infrastructures\portalnekretnine.infrastructures.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\portalnekretnine.models\portalnekretnine.models.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\portalnekretnine.services\portalnekretnine.services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

if any code sample or configuration needed, pls let me know.

thnx

Comment: Q: Do you have a .csproj?  What does it say?  Q: Have you tried --verbose?  Q: Jave you tried [--framework NNN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: Hi - I just checked all the "build files" on one of my Linux projects, and I didn't see anything much besides .csproj.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) *DELETE* bin/* and "obj/*" and rebuild.  Q: Any errors/warnings on Rebuild?  Q: Do you see the files/file versions you expect?  2) Re-run `dotnet publish...`.  Specify `--framework XXX` and `--Verbose` (*NOT* "--verbosity quiet").  Q: Did the error occur?  Did the log output say thing helpful?  3) If the error  is still happening, please copy/paste the exact error into your post.